# Elegant Numpy ways to implement this matrix operation

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking to vectorize the following equation:

[image]

Where x represents an N x T list of observations, and gamma is an N x K matrix. The intended output, theta, is a K x T matrix. Of course, I have a naive implementation that works by just looping through the elements and setting the array manually, but I just know there's a much cleaner solution lurking out here somewhere.

Below is my naive implementation, however it is much too slow for my purposes.

```py
    theta = np.zeros((K, T))
    for k in range(K):
        numerator = np.zeros((T,))
        denominator = 0
        for i in range(N):
            gamma_ik = r[i,k]
            numerator = numerator + gamma_ik * x[i]
            denominator = denominator + gamma_ik
        theta[k] = numerator / denominator
```

Comment: Most of us are programmers; not mathematicians.  We can read your math, but we'd rather see, and build on your "maive implementation". Better yet, demonstrate that you've spent some time learning the basics of `numpy`, such as the use of `np.sum` and `np.dot`.  And don't forget the [mcve]

Comment: Good point. I've added it into the question statement. I tried using np.sum, but I couldn't get the dimensions to work out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly more explicit answer that may be easier to follow. Again, the key function call is [`numpy.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html).

```
import numpy as np

# dimensions N, T, K
N = 2
T = 3
K = 4

x = np.cumsum(np.ones([N,T]), axis = 0)
#[[1. 1. 1.]
#[2. 2. 2.]]

gamma = np.cumsum(np.ones([K,N]), axis = 0)
#[[1. 1.]
# [2. 2.]
# [3. 3.]
# [4. 4.]]

y = np.matmul(gamma, x) # numerator
#[[ 3.  3.  3.]
# [ 6.  6.  6.]
# [ 9.  9.  9.]
# [12. 12. 12.]]

# denominator
sumgamma = np.matmul(gamma, np.ones(N))
#[2. 4. 6. 8.]

theta = y / sumgamma[:,None]
#[[1.5 1.5 1.5]
# [1.5 1.5 1.5]
# [1.5 1.5 1.5]
# [1.5 1.5 1.5]]
```

Comment: Perfect! I was able to implement this easily and got a hefty performance boost. I did end up using `np.sum(gamma.T, axis=0)[:, None])` for the denominator instead though

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are both correct. I just wanted to add that we could also `sum` on axis and `keepdims` to keep the sum as a column vector.

Reusing @ramzeek's input (note that `gamma` is already transposed from construction in their example; here I use the original dimension):

```
N = 2
T = 3
K = 4

X = np.cumsum(np.ones((N,T)), axis = 0)
gamma = np.cumsum(np.ones((N,K)), axis = 0)
```

where `X` is an NxT matrix and `gamma` is an NxK matrix. Then `np.matmul(gamma.T, X)` creates the numerator (of dimension (NxK)' x (NxT) = KxT ) and `gamma.T.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)` creates the denominator (of dimension sum^N(NxK)' = Kx1 ).

You can also use `np.divide` to element-wise divide as well:

```
theta = np.divide(np.matmul(gamma.T, X), gamma.T.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True))
```

then `theta`'s dimension: (KxT / Kx1 = KxT)

Output:

```
array([[1.66666667, 1.66666667, 1.66666667],
       [1.66666667, 1.66666667, 1.66666667],
       [1.66666667, 1.66666667, 1.66666667],
       [1.66666667, 1.66666667, 1.66666667]])
```